# She, as well as I (am/is/are?) tired of the work

Tags: verb-agreement

As I was riding the train with a Japanese colleague, she took notice of this English question posted on one of the ads (about a medicine for stomachaches. Yes, I'm confused as well):

> She, as well as I (?) tired of the work.

I believe the selections for the answer are the following:

> is, are, am, have

I thought the answer is *am* or *is*, but I'm not sure because I haven't seen this sentence structure used before. I know that the subject-verb agreement when using the word *and* will compound the subjects, but I'm not so sure with *as well as*.

I hope someone can explain this thoroughly, as well as point me to the correct answer.

EDIT: I haven't seen the question on the trains again, but I've looked into it thinking the question was part of TOEIC. I've seen this [link](http://melma.com/backnumber_170997_3855533/) (it's in Japanese, and I'm not yet capable of reading it), so please check it out. The formatting there is a lot more weird (no commas?), but I saw the fourth item there.

Comment: Five words to signify "we"?

Comment: @thomas IKR? That's why I said to her "this sentence isn't used most of the time". The placing of 'I' seems pretty weird, and comes of as intentional, as to confuse readers.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the accepted answer is correct. I would suggest the following: "I am, as well as her, tired of work" (OR) She is, as well as me, tired of work" (OR) She is, as well as I am, tired of work.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just saw that question on an ad, it's a multiple choice question. The format of the sentence doesn't matter. And I forgot some details (4th selection, comma after 'as') so I'll be updating the question as soon as I saw that ad again. But for now, I think the answer is consistent with the rule, though the structure is not what you encounter every day.

Comment: For grammar info, there's this answer post: [What is the correct verb that follows "as well as?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/174366/57102).

Comment: Also, for an example to show that the plural verb is possible, there is in *MWCDEU*, page 102, this: "He, as well as the producer, Jack H. Silverman, are Broadway newcomers -- *N.Y. Times*".

Comment: @F.E. - Thank you. You are a great resource. Now if only I could convince you to write answers! :D

Comment: Also, notice that ***"I is"*** doesn't sound too good to one's ear, not as standard English. Even with commas, like in *"She, as well as I, is tired of the work"*, it will need a real long pause between "I" and "is", and even then, it still sounds awkward.

Comment: Why use an optional contraction rule at all? Repetition is effective in conveying emotion; that's one of its principal uses. If you want to avoid repeating the predicate, use a tag: _She's tired of the work, and so am I._

Comment: @F.E.during my quest for this certain question, I've seen one more awkward sentence. "He, as well as we" was used. I think it's really just to make it confusing for the reader, since they're not native speakers. [This link](http://e4u.ybmsisa.com/TOEIC/ToeicPlaza/easy/easy_view.asp?questionSEQ=92350&md=S&categoryCode=025001000&iPage=&list_search=1&list_search_key=&order_type=&nowPage=) has it, though now it's in Korean.

Comment: Speakers of languages without subject-verb agreement tend to overestimate the number of awkward sentences English speakers emit. Native speakers learn to avoid those constructions very young, precisely because they do feel awkward, either way. So Asian students get drilled (using the wrong rules, often enough) on the problems with our number agreement system, while we native speakers do our best to make number agreement irrelevant, unnecessary, and  inaudible.

Comment: Just to echo (I think) John Lawler's view, I would never give "She, as well as I [am/is/are] tired of the work" a pass into a publication I was working on. No matter which option you choose, the awkwardness and unnaturalness of the construction will bring the flow of the narrative to a lurching halt while the reader tries to figure out (1) whether the choice is justifiable on technical grounds, and (2) why the author chose to express the idea in such needlessly cement-headed prose. The point of writing isn't to be ostentatiously (or merely arguably) correct; it's to convey ideas well. /sermon

Comment: In situations like this I find it much easier to just say "She and me is both done had enough of all this". If you are going to sin, sin boldly - right?

Comment: @BrianDHall +1 for teh lulz. But I think I've never seen a Japanese throw a fit while at work, especially not in English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct verb that follows "as well as?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-is-the-correct-verb-that-follows-as-well-as)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little knowledge, so they say, is a dangerous thing. It is commonly noted that the phrase "as well as" + [noun] is 'parenthetical'. And, indeed, this is sometimes true. It is this fact, aided and abetted by dreary prescriptive usage guides that motivates the guidance, frequently seen, that the noun after *as well as* should have no bearing on the agreement of the following verb in examples like the OP's. However,  a visit to a modern, reputable and vetted grammar source, such as the world famous and awe-inspiring, *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston & Pullum  (et al), 2002, will reveal a more complex and interesting story.

They, as well as usage guides such as the *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage*,  point out that *as well as* is sometimes a co-ordinator. To make this clearer, we should say that there is an altogether different lexeme *as well as*, which is homophonous with the parenthetical phrase *as well as*. The so-called parenthetical one, is actually a two-word adverb followed by the preposition *as* and whatever complement this preposition takes. The co-ordinator is a three word  co-ordinator.

Now the co-ordinator *as well as* functions similarly to the co-ordinator *and*. There are all sorts of syntactic tests we can do and observations we can make to show that this item is a co-ordinator. One important aspect of co-ordinated subjects is that the co-ordination counts as plural in terms of its contribution to the number agreement of the verb. So we see for example:

- Bob and I **are** very happy.

We don't however see:

- *Bob and I is very happy.

Neither do we usually observe:

- *Bob and I am happy.

CaGEL (2002, p. 1316) give the following real examples showing *as well as* used as a co-ordinator. Notice that the noun phrase co-ordinations cause plural verb form agreement:

> - 70 i. b. _[Abstraction] [as well as impressionism] were Russian inventions.
> - 70 i. c. _[Both increasing ewe liveweight,] [as well as liveweight at mating,] influence ovulation rate and lambing performance.

In the examples above we see the plural verb forms *were* and *influence*, not *was* and *influences* - just like we would see with the co-ordinator *and*:

- [Abstraction] [and impressionism] were Russian inventions.
- [Both increasing ewe liveweight,] [and liveweight at mating,] influence ovulation rate and lambing performance.

They, however, also give sentences where a homophonous *as well as* phrase (which includes the following NP) functions as adjunct:

> - 70.ii.a Beauty, as well as love, is redemptive.

Note that it doesn't seem to make any difference when the *as well as* section is marked of by commas. Merriam-Webster (p. 102) give the following example from the New York Times, where the phrase is delimited by commas:

- He, as well as the producer, Jack H. Silverman, are Broadway newcomers.

So, in short, it would seem that either:

- She as well as I is tired of the work

and

- She as well as I are tired of the work

... should be ok. Bear in mind, however, that  their structures would actually be very different. Having said this, the fact that the two subjects are pronouns makes the second version considerably preferable to the first. The combination *I is* is particularly nasty, and jarring to ones natural ear. Only dimwitted, slavish adherence to prescriptive usage guides could make one prefer the former.

Now, having said *that*, let us also bear in mind that given that the structures are only superficially similar - even if similar in meaning and similar in the audible or visual sequence of words - one might be better off choosing an altogether different wording for this sentence. Let's face it, neither is particularly elegant. The highfalutin effect of *as well as* is slightly kiboshed, imo, by the pronouns and the short sentence. There are other emphatic devices that we may want to use - especially if we have a prescriptivist "grammar"-pedant for an editor!

**Edit note**: many thanks to F.E. for suggestions and the MWDEU citation.

Comment: It is lovely to see an authoritative answer that also makes sense. Thanks for your time! I will use this happily.

Comment: Now this is explaining "things thoroughly". I'll choose this as the answer. Thanks. I think this would apply for similarly awkward structures such as "He, as well as we", am I correct?

Comment: @IBG Yes, definitely, imo. *He as well as we is happy* is definitely very painful! :)

Comment: It is indeed very painful to the senses, even for a non-native like me. I have been thinking of taking TOEIC this year. I hope it's not full of questions like these.

Comment: I imagine that the sentence would be vastly improved if we replace "as well as" with "and." Then it would be "She and I are..."

Answer (score 10):

The subject is only “She”. The subject is therefore singular, and so "is" is correct.

The “as well as I” clause is an adverbial aside, not part of the main clause.

Thus, "She, as well as I, is tired of the work."

Consider another adverbial aside:

> Frank, along with Tomoko, lives in Kyoto.

The verb here is also singular for the same reason.

Comment: Can you please explain what "adverbial aside" means? I haven't seen these two words put together, so I want to know what it means in this context. That aside, it's a clear explanation. Just to be clear, it works on plural forms too, am I correct? For example "She, as well as her friends is tired of the work".

Comment: I'd call what you call an 'adverbial aside' a parenthetical, in this case a free modifier giving reasonably closely related additional information. As a parenthetical, omitting it indicates the correct agreement. With 'Fred (and his friends) is/are coming', this 'rule' begins to look shaky.

Comment: Er, no. This answer is not right.

Comment: @F.E. care to answer it authoritatively? I'll retract my selection for now, as it seems like no one's up for medica's bounty because there's already a selected correct answer.

Comment: @IBG - the bounty is up to me to confer. The upvoted answer does not influence that.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence should be "She, as well as I, **is** tired of the work".

The section in commas is merely an aside and added on. The main phrase is still "She **is** tired of the work". The verb does not change in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> She, as well as I, is tired of the work.

= She is tired of the work (and I am as well).

*She is the subject of the verb 'to be', so it must be 'is'. The 'as well as I' is parenthetical - it can be removed, and the sentence will still make sense (she is tired of the work). Most people would pause around the 'as well as I', hence the commas.*

The sentence could also work without anything in there:

> She, as well as I, tired of the work.

= She tired of the work (and I did as well).

Some other verb is also possible:

> She, as well as I, became tired of the work.

= She became tired of the work (and I did as well).

*The verb 'to tire', which is somewhat formal, means the same as the more common 'to become tired'.*

Depending on context, 'am' is a possibility:

> She, as well, as I am tired of the work.

= She also (did whatever was in the preceding sentence), because I am tired of the work.

*'She' is the subject an implied repetition of the preceding verb and 'I' is the suject of 'to be', which is therefore 'am'*

In all cases the 'as well as I' construction is unwieldy and a far more natural way of saying it would be:

> She and I are (both) tired of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my forever buggy English, here is my take on this bogus:
*She as well as I are tired of the work.*

In my own (Bulgarian) language we say:
*Tya kakto i az SME izmoreni ot rabotata.*
**SME=ARE**

Fellow participants, I am a big fan of dealing with n-gram aspect of English, just see:
https://www.google.bg/search?q=%22i+are+tired%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=KtS6VOiOOeH_ywOtpoKYCg

There, the first 3-gram is from **English Grammar: Step by Step - Page 41**:
*Sam and I are tired.*

Second excerpt is from **Letters to Padre Pio - Page 88**:
*It's a fatiguing wait, Padre; and Penny and I are tired of the whole process.*

In my view 'as well as' does not change anything, interestingly it transforms the subject 'She' into plural as in:
**United States Congressional serial set - Volume 11731 - Page 40**:
***He as well as I are*** very lonesome without her.
Notice the optional commas, in many instances 'as well as' is surrounded by them.

Strangely enough, the 2012 Google Books corpus (2+ million books) shows only 20 usages of "he as well as i are", perhaps because it is a 6-gram while main datasets are up to 5-gram!

@medica Hi, give these precious points to me, they will come strengthifying, with them I am gonna be able to comment, now the site requires 50 points to do so.

Answer (score -3):

IS is wrong.  ARE, from your choices is best.

The fourth one might have been GOT.  As in "She, as well as I GOT tired of the work.

### Still I think ARE would be most correct.

edit:

As pointed out graciously by F.E. (thank you again) and referenced in the question here: [What is the correct verb that follows "as well as?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-is-the-correct-verb-that-follows-as-well-as/174366#174366)

In this case 'as well as' is behaving as the coordinator 'and', so if we take teh original sentence and look at it this way:
"She and I is tired of the work"
It's immediately clear to any native speaker that this is poor and incorrect in English.
We would immediately tend towards "She and I /are/ tired of the work"

The linked question is well supported with references from MWCDEU and others.

Comment: You're wrong. "She" is the subject of the sentence, so the verb would be "is."

Comment: I'm no english major so I can't quote the rules of the grammar but "She, as well as I is tired of the work" doesn't sound right in spoken english.  It kind of sound illiterate or ESL.  Perhaps if there was a comma between I and is but as it's written, I just don't see it.

Comment: JoelAZ, it does sound a bit stilted or unnatural, but would you say that for any sentence with the same structure? How about "Frank, as well as Bob, works on Saturday."

Comment: @curious-proofreader - I would not say the same of your example.  Your example may not be 'everyday' language for most people but it does not sound problematic or unnatural to me as the OP question does with the word IS filled in.

Comment: Thinking further, your example doesn't present the same quandary as the OP since 'works on Saturday' is correct regardless of it refers to Frank or both Frank and Bob.  The OP's example DOES change because of the second person in the sentence. "She is tired of the work" is fine.  "I is tired of the work" is not.  Also, you added that comma, which as I stated, might make the difference between whether IS is acceptable in the OP's sentence.  Without, it just sounds... broken.

Comment: BTW, @Nicole - "She" is not the ONLY subject of the sentence.  "I" refers to a second person, who is ALSO a subject.  Therefore I don't think the answer is quite as black and white as your rationale.  I don't mind my answer w/ no votes but I don't think it deserves downvoting.

Comment: @JoelAZ "It kind of sound illiterate or ESL." Indeed it is, since I'm from Japan (though not Japanese) and even I think this sentence structure sounds odd. I think the intention is to confuse people with the notion that there is an 'I' over there, which makes you think "ah, it should be am". If ever I saw the ad on the train again, I'll update the question to address the fourth selection, as well as if there is indeed a comma between the item to be filled in, and the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @IBG - The ESL comment was in no way directed at you;  hope you didn't read it that way.  I meant it to support my answer against Nicole's terse comment and assertion that my answer was flat "wrong".  Maybe I AM wrong, but if so I'd like to see the rule book that says so.  Best I can tell that sentence has two subjects and, perhaps more importantly, to my ear "IS" just sounds like rubbing a cheese grater on your face would feel.  I would definitely be interested in you filling in the rest of the blanks on that questions though so please, at your earliest convenience, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It is sometimes easier to figure out what to do with conjunctions by imagining two separate sentences. "Frank lives in Kyoto." and "Tomoko lives in Kyoto." Joining them with a conjunction does not transform the subject into the plural form.

Comment: @JoelAZ of course, I just added it in case someone wonders about the context of the question (why it sounds weird, how the heck it relates to a stomach medicine advertisement, etc). I think there was a comma there, but I'm not sure, so I hope I hop on the train with the said ad (since it differs per train). As per the rule, I dug more into it, and saw this: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp
Look at rule 5.

Comment: Thanks @IBG.  That does seem to be applicable/authoritative here.  I still think it sounds plain wrong though so I'd never structure a sentence that way.  Guess you learn smth new everyday!  Now I just need a couple more votes and I can delete my answer! :)  (Thx HunterHogan too. That helps understand some as well.)

Comment: +1. The crowd is usually wrong. :)

Comment: For grammar info, there's this answer post: [What is the correct verb that follows "as well as?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/174366/57102). Example [70.i.c] might be interesting for you. :)

Comment: Also, for an example to show that the plural verb is possible, there is in *MWCDEU*, page 102, this: "He, as well as the producer, Jack H. Silverman, are Broadway newcomers -- *N.Y. Times*".

Comment: Thank you F.E.!!  I knew it sounded odd but without the English degree couldn't support my position well.  I've always deferred to my ear/instincts on this stuff as, for whatever reason, my instincts are generally good in this discipline.  The linked question is spot on IMO so thank you.   @IBG check out F.E.'s link.  IMO this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Joel, the reason "is" doesn't sound correct to you is because the sentence structure in this instance is so unusual. As the Curious Proofreader mentioned, "as well as I", is a non-essential aside. If you remove it the main point of the sentence is unaffected and it becomes plain what the verb tense should be, "She, [ ], *is* tired of the work." Granted the missing comma only adds to the challenge. I don't feel you deserved so many down votes. :-)

Comment: Also, notice that ***"I is"*** doesn't sound too good to one's ear, not as standard English. Even with commas, like in *"She, as well as I, is tired of the work"*, it will need a real long pause between "I" and "is", and even then, it still sounds awkward.

Comment: If the word in the "as well as" phrase is plural, do we still use a singular verb? Jack, as well as his brothers, IS scheduled to be there. Thank you.