# "X as well as Y" ; will this be followed by singular verb or plural verb?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

**"X as well as Y" singular or plural** 
When two nouns are connected using "as well as", does that become singular or plural?
For eg. *Sam as well as his brother Dean **has / have** to come*.
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use "has" since Sam is the subject of the sentence. *As well as Dean* is just a phrase used to add detail.

> Sam (as well as his brother Dean) has to come.

You should also consider adding commas:

> Sam, as well as his brother(,) Dean, has to come.

Answer (score 0):

That construction is awkward and unnecessary as the subject. Just say Sam and his brother Dean have to come, or Sam and Dean have to come.

Comment: The above sentence is just an example. My doubt is with the general usage of "as well as" connecting multiple nouns or pronouns.