# was and were in the form "X, along with the Y's, [was/were] Z"

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, compound-subjects

Consider the sentence:

> The aristocracy, as well as powerful merchant guilds, were viewed as restrictive to trade.

Should this be

> The aristocracy, as well as powerful merchant guilds, was viewed as restrictive to trade.

How could it make sense in the latter case, since we are talking about a plurality of "merchant guilds"?

Comment: In the first place, *aristocracy* itself can probably take either *was* or *were* depending on if one is using it as a collective noun. But to answer your question, subject-verb concord usually ignores phrases as *as well as*/*along with*/and others.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Actually, not quite so clear cut once you get into it. [Here's a great post by F.E.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-is-the-correct-verb-that-follows-as-well-as) on a similar question. (p.s. that question needs some reopen votes)

Answer (score 1):

The  subordinate clause doesn't make the subject pleural. The verb is the same without it:

> The aristocracy [was|were] viewed as restrictive to trade.

Try it with a simpler set of nouns:

> Peter, as well as Paul and Mary, [was|were] singing.

I think that it is clearly a singular *was* particularly if you rearrange the sentence to:

> As well as Paul and Mary, Peter was singing.

The ambiguity in your example sentence comes from the fact that *the aristocracy* could be either singular or pleural depending on whether you view it as a unified block or a collection of individuals.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of intent. If the commas are being used parenthetically, I should conclude that the latter construction is more correct. However, if (as I suspect) the intent is to group the aristocracy and guilds together, then the former is more accurate.